# The jQuery file not getting loaded in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to load the jQuery files to the Django. But its not working for me. When I write the code inside the `script` tag inside the `Head` it works perfectly. I wrote the code in a file called main.js

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
  <link rel="text/javascript" href="{% static 'js/main.js' %}">
```

This is my static path in settings

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

How can I load the jQuery file in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML's `link` is used to load `stylesheet` -- `CSS` not `JavaScript` file.

You have to load javascript with `script` tag.

so like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/main.js %}"></script>
```

REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script